# Hyperlinks and buttons not selectable on iPhone - works on all other browsers

Tags: iphone, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

Help!!  I am having a massive headache over getting the links to work on the iPhone for my portfolio site.

The site in question: [redraptordesigns.com](http://redraptordesigns.com/)

It works great on all browsers, everything is fully functional, **except** on the iPhone - only the top nav bar links work.  Nothing else is selectable.  You can't click (or touch) and of buttons or regular links on any of the pages.  You can't even select the text.

I've tried a lot of different fixes with no avail.

Oh, and I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: It takes ages to load; why?

Comment: On mobile? Or regular browser?  It load super quick for me on a regular browser and about 6 seconds slower on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

First you are using the new [Safari 6 Web Inspector support for Debugging Mobile Safari](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/) it is my new best friend.

I'm not sure what else is going on but your close tags are backwards.

```
<p itemprop="description">
  <a href="#services"> 
    Web Design &middot; U.I. Design &middot; Web Dev &middot; Sound Design &middot; Graphics
  </p>
</a>
```

You also have [40 Markup Validation Error](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=redraptordesigns.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) that you need to track down and fix.